# Does my Dryad Arbor stop being a creature with a Blood Moon in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does my [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDryad%20Arbor%5d) stop being a creature with [Blood Moon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Moon%5d) in play?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does not.

Taken from the rulings found here:

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=282542

"If Dryad Arbor is changed into another basic land type (such as by Sea’s Claim), it continues to be a creature and a Dryad."

Blood Moon would turn it into another basic land type, in this case a Mountain, so it would continue to be a creature and a Dryad.

========

Edit:

With regards to Blood Sun, this too will not stop Dryad Arbor being a creature.

Blood sun simply removes any abilities that are not mana abilities (i.e. abilities that generate mana). Being a creature is not considered an ability, but a type, so Dryad Arbor would still be considered a creature. See below:

305.7. If an effect sets a land’s subtype to one or more of the basic land types, the land no longer has its old land type. It loses all abilities generated from its rules text, its old land types, and any copy effects affecting that land, and it gains the appropriate mana ability for each new basic land type. Note that this doesn’t remove any abilities that were granted to the land by other effects. **Setting a land’s subtype doesn’t add or remove any card types (such as creature)** or supertypes (such as basic, legendary, and snow) the land may have. If a land gains one or more land types in addition to its own, it keeps its land types and rules text, and it gains the new land types and mana abilities.

Comment: Is the same true when you have a blood sun in play?

Comment: @Neil You should ask that in a new question. Adding additional question scope like this in comments isn't considered good practice on SE.

Comment: For an even more recent example, Alpine Moon also would not keep Dryad Arbor from being a creature since it only causes them to "lose all **land types** and abilities". So Dryad Arbor would no longer be a Forest, but it would still be a land creature.

Answer (score 6):

**No, it will stay a creature.**

Blood Moon only affects the subtype and original/copied abilities of affected permanents.

The only difference is that instead of being a

> Land Creature - Forest Dryad,

it will be a

> Land Creature - Mountain Dryad.

If Dryad Arbor gained any other abilities later, such as flying, it will retain them. It merely loses the "{T}: {G}" ability granted to it from the Forest basic land type, and instead gains "{T}:{R}" from the Mountain basic land type.

> 305.7. If an effect sets a land’s subtype to one or more of the basic land types, the land no longer has its old land type. It loses all abilities generated from its rules text, its old land types, and any copy effects affecting that land, and it gains the appropriate mana ability for each new basic land type. Note that this doesn’t remove any abilities that were granted to the land by other effects. Setting a land’s subtype doesn’t add or remove any card types (such as creature) or supertypes (such as basic, legendary, and snow) the land may have. If a land gains one or more land types in addition to its own, it keeps its land types and rules text, and it gains the new land types and mana abilities.

As an example, if you had [Dimir Doppelganger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDimir%20Doppelganger%5d) copy a Dryad Arbor, the resulting creature would be a 1/1 Mountain Dryad without any abilities except the red mana ability as long as Blood Moon is on the battlefield; specifically, the dryad would lose the Doppelganger's ability to switch to another creature.

Comment: Does the same ruling apply when you have a blood sun in play?

Comment: @NeilMeyer no. Blood Sun doesn't interact with Dryad Arbor at all, since its only ability is a mana ability ({T}: Add {G}).

Comment: If you copy Dryad Arbor with the Doppelganger, it grants the ability to itself after the copying process. This is then no longer part of its text. So the "doesn’t remove any abilities that were granted to the land by other effects" exception mentioned in 305.7 applies. The Doppelganger keeps his ability to exile and thus copy other creature cards from graveyards.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp *706.9. Copy effects may include modifications or exceptions to the copying process.
706.9a Some copy effects cause the copy to gain an ability as part of the copying process. This ability becomes part of the copiable values for the copy, along with any other abilities that were copied.* Gaining the Doppelganger ability is part of the copy effect and therefore erased by Blood Moon.

Comment: Folks, please. We shouldn't be letting people ask completely out-of-scope follow-up questions *in the comments.* That's not how we do things, it's considered a bad faith use of the network and we should not be enabling it. @NeilMeyer Please either ask a new question so we can store these answers permanently *or* update your question if you think it should also cover the Blood Sun scope.