# Does Dryad Arbor remain a creature with Blood Sun in play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=282542) remain a creature with [Blood Sun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439749) in play?

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42849/does-my-dryad-arbor-stop-being-a-creature-with-a-blood-moon-in-play).

Comment: Note that Dryad Arbor originally had the ability "Dryad Arbor is Green", but it no longer has that ability. The ability was replaced with a color indicator.

Comment: I had to read both questions 3 times before I realized why they weren't the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's still a creature, because Blood Sun causes it only to loose non-mana abilities. The Creature subtype is not an ability.

Comment: Power and Toughness are also usually not abilities, though there are exceptions.

Comment: Abilities can set or modify power and toughness, but power and toughness themselves are not abilities.